# WPF Caliburn Micro CanExecute when property of binded object changes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have the problem, that my `CanSave` method doesn't get called, when I change a binded property.

## View

The View contains of some `Labels` and `TextBoxes`... nothing special...

The TextBoxes are binded to the properties of an object.

```
<Label Target="{Binding ElementName=txtTitle}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Titel" Foreground="White" />
<TextBox Name="txtTitle" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding NewBook.Title}" />

<Label Target="{Binding ElementName=txtAuthor}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Autor" Foreground="White" />
<TextBox Name="txtAuthor" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding NewBook.Author}"/>

<Label Target="{Binding ElementName=txtIsbn}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Content="ISBN" Foreground="White" />
<TextBox Name="txtIsbn" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding NewBook.Isbn}" />

<Label Target="{Binding ElementName=txtPrice}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Content="Preis" Foreground="White" />
<TextBox Name="txtPrice" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding NewBook.Price}"/>

<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Content="Speichern" Name="SaveBook" />
```

## ViewModel

The ViewModel defines the property `NewBook` and the methods `CanSaveBook` and `SaveBook`

```
public Book NewBook
{
    get { return this.newBook; }
    set
    {
        this.newBook = value;
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.NewBook);
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.CanSaveBook);
    }
}

public bool CanSaveBook
{
    get
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.NewBook.Title) 
                && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.NewBook.Author)
                && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.NewBook.Isbn) 
                && this.NewBook.Price != 0;
    }
}

public void SaveBook()
{
    try
    {
        this.xmlOperator.AddBook(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("BookXmlPath"), this.NewBook);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    this.NewBook = new Book();
}
```

What I want is, that the `Save-Button` is only available, when `CanSaveBook` returns `true` but that the `CanSaveBook`-Method is checked after the user enters information in the textboxes... what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that changing a property of the book does not raise INotifyPropertyChange on the view model. Easiest would be to get rid of the Book class and put the Name, Price, ISBN properties straight in the view model. Then raise INotifyPropertyChange in the setters (and make sure that the binding is two-way).

You can then construct the Book in the SaveBook method and call your service with it.

Comment: Ok cool that was what I would have done too but I thought there was a "more beautiful" solution. There is another problem tough: The Button only gets enabled after exiting the last textbox.. how can I execute the CanSaveBook-Method after every keyup without any code-behind?

Comment: Set UpdateSourceTrigger on your TextBox to PropertyChanged (defaults is LostFocus)