# CanExecute Caliburn method not working with nested properties

Tags: c#, .net, caliburn.micro

I am trying to use the Caliburn Micro CanExecute method to bind my save button to be disabled or not based on if value is entered in a text box.

Here is my View:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Current.Name}"/>
<Button Content="Save" Name="Save" />
```

My POCO:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged] (fody)
public partial class POCO: IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And my ViewModel:

```
public void SetupViewModel()
{
    Current = new POCO();
}

public POCO Current { get; set; }

public bool CanSave => Current == null || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Current?.Name);
```

If I setup a variable and bind it in the view instead (let's call it `POCOName`) and pass that into `CanSave` it works fine, seems to just be an issue with the nested properties. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I found [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32333022/wpf-caliburn-micro-canexecute-when-property-of-binded-object-changes) that seems to be similar, but a solution to this was never found, just a reccomendation to do it a different way. Is there anyway for it to work like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Action conventions feature use x:Name directive not Name property.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Current.Name}"/>
<Button Content="Save" x:Name="Save" />
```

**Update**
I already tried to use Name property it also work too, sorry for gave you wrong information.

CanExcute method in your case is actually a property, you need to notify property changed, for example.

```
public string Name
{ 
    get { return _name; }
    set
    {
        _name = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(Name));
        // when Name changed, check if it is null or whitespace
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(CanSave));
    }
}
```

it depend on you application where to notify CanExcute property changed.
You also can use CanExcute method,  it will be called every time the value of parameter changed.
For more information about Caliburn Micro Action see [All About Actions](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/actions)

Comment: @wut I already update my answer sorry for gave you wrong information.